# Load an exe file and set a variable from web page

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have recently been making a game in Unity (C#) and at the start a variable is set to a number. The number is a seed which is used to generate a 2d world out of blocks. This means that if the number is 5 then it will generate the same world for everyone using the seed 5.

I would like to upload seeds to my webpage so when a user clicks a button, the compiled unity application (.EXE) opens and the "seed" variable is set to a certain number depending on which button is pressed. For instance I could make a button which loads the program with the seed variable set to '5', or I could load it with the seed variable set to number '8'.

I am wondering if this is possible due to the file being complied and if so how would I do it? I have the code to load a .EXE file here:

```
<a href="file:///C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe">Click me</a>
```

Sorry if I am a bit too specific or confusing, this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fortunately it's incredibly easy to load a text file from the internet, in Unity.

```
void Start()
 {
 Debug.Log("i will now get the file at http://url.com/temp/hello.txt");
 StartCoroutine(ReadFile());
 }

private IEnumerator ReadFile()
{
WWW w = new WWW("http://url.com/temp/hello.txt");
yield return w;
if (w.error != null)
 {
 .. error
 yield break;
 }
else
 {
 string result = w.text;
 Debug.Log("the web page is: result);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that will help however what I need is a button on my website which loads the program and then sets a variable to a value in the button. I am wondering if this is possible due to it being compiled?

Comment: I see what I did wrong now. I wrote "so when a user clicks a button" and you thought I meant when the user clicks a button in unity but I what I actually meant was when a user clicks a button in the web page. Sorry I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: in any event definitely ask a new question and me or someone will help!